# What's a point of starting a project in Intellij in Run mode?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, project

Everyone in our company is starting a project in debugging mode. Any person I've talked to from other companies starts their project in debugging mode. 
It's the same as run but allows you to add a breakpoint at any time. If I decide to check how my code behaves I will have to restart in debugging mode. Both modes seem to be starting at the same speed, so performance doesn't seem to be a point.
So, my question is whether there is any benefit of using Run (Shift + F10) instead of Debug(Shift + F9)?

Comment: You don't need to mute breakpoint when you start application in run mode.

Comment: Well, I hotkeyed "mute all"  for that purpose, so this doesn't seem to be that big of an advantage

Comment: From this point there is no difference. Running in debug mode only means that process will look for breakpoints to stop. For some configurations separate external process is started to support debug features.